# How do I successfully add objects to a private list?

Tags: c#

The public method "NyBok" works when I use stepinto and it adds what I want to the list, but when I try to show the list with `VisaBöcker()` the list is empty.

```cs
{
    class Bibliotikarie
    {
        private List<Bok> Böcker = new List<Bok>();     
        public static void VisaBöcker()
        {
            var gg = new Bibliotikarie();
            foreach (Bok item in gg.Böcker)  
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("\"" + item.Titel + "\" av " + item.Skribent + ". År " + item.UtÅr + ".  ( " + item.Typ + " )");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }  
        public static void NyBok()
        {
             var gg = new Bibliotikarie();
             gg.Böcker.Add(new Roman(TitSvar, FörSvar, ÅrSvar));               
        }     
    }

         class Bok                  
         {
             public string Titel;    
             public string Skribent;
             public string Typ;
             public int UtÅr;
         }

         class Roman : Bok         
         {
             public Roman(string _Titel, string _Skribent, int _UtÅr)
             {
                 Titel = _Titel;
                 Skribent = _Skribent;
                 UtÅr = _UtÅr;
                 base.Typ = "Roman";                         
             }
```

(The code for `NyBok()` is shortened down because it's a lot of unnecessary code for the user in Swedish.)

Comment: It would be much easier to understand your question if you kept it to English. However, your problem arises in creating `Bibliotikarie` objects where you shouldn't be. `NyBok`, which I guess is "NewBook", shouldn't be part of the `Roman` class, but rather an *instance member* of `Bibliotikarie`. `VisaBöcker()` should also be an instance member rather than static

Comment: The function `VisaBöcker` creates a new `Bibliotikarie`, which has initially an empty `Böcker` list. When you added items to the `Böcker` list, it was in a different instance of `Bibliotikarie`.

Comment: Seems like that would be the problem. How do I use the same instance?

Comment: You have too many libraries (`new Bibliotikarie()`) -- the one where you put the book is not the same one where you go looking for it

Comment: Thats because {gg} of {VisaBöcker} method is not {gg} of {NyBok} as you defined them in different scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *NyBok* you create an new instance of the class *Bibliotikarie* and then add items to its *Böcker* variable. You can do this only because the class *Roman* is internal to the class *Bibliotikarie* otherwise being the variable *Böcker* private you cannot use it externally from the *Bibliotikarie* class.

However the *gg* variable created in the method is local and when you exit from that method that variable is discarded and everything in it is destroyed.
Now when you call the method *VisaBöcker* you create another instance of the class *Bibliotikarie* and this instance has a new List obviously empty.

I would change a lot of logic in your code. First and foremost it shouldn't be the responsability of the class *Roman* to add items to the *Bibliotikarie*, next I would extract the internal classes from the *Bibliotikarie* class and make them accessible to an external code that handle a *Bibliotikarie* instance.

Now we could have

```
public class Bibliotikarie
{
    private List<Bok> Böcker = new List<Bok>();

    // This method adds a Bok instance or a derived one to your list
    public void AddBok(Bok b)
    {
        Böcker.Add(b);
    }

    public void VisaBöcker()
    {
        foreach (Bok item in Böcker)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\r\n\"{item.Titel}\" av {item.Skribent}. År {item.UtÅr}.  ( {item.Typ} )\r\n");
        }
    }
}
public class Bok
{
    public string Titel;
    public string Skribent;
    public string Typ;
    public int UtÅr;
}

public class Roman : Bok
{
    public Roman(string _Titel, string _Skribent, int _UtÅr)
    {
        Titel = _Titel;
        Skribent = _Skribent;
        UtÅr = _UtÅr;
        base.Typ = "Roman";
    }
}
```

This structure will allow to write code like this

```
void Main()
{
    Bibliotikarie bb = new Bibliotikarie();
    bb.AddBok(new Roman("Example1", "Test1", 1));
    bb.AddBok(new Roman("Example2", "Test2", 2));
    bb.VisaBöcker();
}
```

Now you have only one instance of the class *Bibliotikarie*, add items to this instance and display them from the same instance that contains the filled list.

Comment: Problem is that the list is private. The foreach loop doesn't work, neither does the AddBok(Bok b) since "CS0120  C# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"

Comment: Sorry but this problen isn't present in the code that I have posted. Are you sure that you have removed all the _static_ modifiers to the classes and their methods and variables?

Comment: You're right, I didn't do that! I read up more about static modifiers which also helped. The problem is solved, thank you